# jQuery Mobile in UIWebView Clipping Content When UIWebView Isn't Full Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

I have a `UIWebView` that is smaller than the full screen (specifically 540x560 pixels). My issue is that my [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) content is being cut off rather than resizing as I would expect a responsive website to do. I've uploaded a sample project with the issue [here](http://cl.ly/2M2S1Y0u1d2e). Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width and height of the viewport to whatever the height of your UIWebView. This will register the "bottom" of the browser window and should prevent your content from being cut off if it is the appropriate height.

See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Answer (score 2):

check following tag in head section of html which tells browser to make width of viewport to same as device width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Remove that tag will remove horizontal scroll

**EDIT:**

you can not remove meta tag form http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/index.html so host it on local server.

Answer (score -1):

Ok @Kevin, only you have doing is resize your `UIWebView` class in `KSViewController.xib`. If you want to make your app a web app, only have you add your favorite framework and folder on Xcode project.

[image]

[image]

**Hope this helps. :)**